# Apache не работает

Tags: apache, apache2

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Запустил apache
c:\Apache24\bin\httpd.exe -k start
Всё ок.

На первой картинке - вход на сервер через ip - не работает.
На второй через localhost - всё работает.

Подскажите что делать.
Если что я новичок.  Делаю всё в первый раз. Возможно упустил какую-то деталь.

Answer (score 0):

Убедитесь, что у одного из ваших адаптеров на ПК действительно IP-адрес 109.252.80.127, что этот адаптер включен, что брандмауер не блокирует доступ на этот IP по порту TCP 80, и что в настройках самого апача разрешено слушать адаптер с данным адресом.